# Single file force merge

Tags: git

I have some kind of "automerge" (dev->master) which works perfectly with one exception.
We have file config/xx/yy/build.properties

Every time I got conflict with this file. I tried to add this file to .git/info/exclude, tried git --assume-unchanged and even add .gitignore file to directory. But always I got conflict.

So I have a question. Can I do "force merge" on single file?

Comment: What is your *“kind of ‘automerge’”* you are talking about? And what would a *“force merge”* be? If it was always possible to automatically merge a file, there wouldn’t be this thing called *merge conflict*. It is just not possible, so a ”forced merge” (whatever that is) can still cause conflicts.

Comment: try to use ```git stash``` before

Comment: If you want to ignore this file, you'll need to remove it from both branches before merging.